# Does $L^1(\mathbb R)$ implies $\limsup_{n\to\infty} f(nx)<\infty$ for almost every $x\in\mathbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

**Question:** Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ be non-negative. Is the proposition

$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} f(nx)<\infty
$$

true for almost every $x$ in $\mathbb R$?

What I have been trying to prove is

$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n f(nx)<\infty,\quad \text{a.e. }x\in\mathbb R
$$

for each real-values sequence $\{a_n\}$ that decreases to $0$. I think Fubini's theorem might help, but I have no way of doing that.

Comment: it is unclear to me why you add the $a_n$ term. How does this relate to the main question?

Comment: also: have you tried constructing a counterexample?

Comment: @supinf In my point of view, the sequence $\{b_n\}$ is bounded if and only if $a_nb_n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ for each $\{a_n\}$ that decreases to zero. No counterexamples have been constructed within my knowledge.

Comment: The solution is already presented here. https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00276738/document